# Close responsive top-nav bar menu after clicking a link in a single page. Foundation 6

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

Hope someone can help me. I have a single page with anchor points in foundation In a mobile view I would like that after clicking a link the menu closes automatically. There is not much information about foundation.

Here is a [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/MI5Studio/pen/eKwXXw)

```
     <nav class="top-bar topbar-responsive" data-sticky data-options="stickyOn:small;"  data-margin-top="0">
  <div class="top-bar-title" >
    <span data-responsive-toggle="topbar-responsive" data-hide-for="medium">
      <button class="menu-icon" type="button" data-toggle></button>
    </span>

    <a class="topbar-responsive-logo" href="#inicio" data-smooth-scroll>TITLE</a>
  </div>
  <div id="topbar-responsive" class="topbar-responsive-links">
    <div class="top-bar-right">
      <ul class="menu simple vertical medium-horizontal" data-magellan data-options="animationEasing: swing; animationDuration: 1000;">
          <li><a href="#inicio">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#1">one</a></li>
        <li><a href="#2">two</a></li>



      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<section id="1">
  <h2>1</h2>
</section>
<section id="2">
  <h2>2</h2>
</section>
```

Comment: Like this? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PBoRKw

Comment: Thats exactly what I wanted. Many thanks for your quick response. Now that I see your code I can understand your solution. It was really helpful. Many thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add a minor snippet to your code in ordet to make it work:

```
$(function(){
   $(document).foundation();    
   $('.menu>li').click(function(){
      $('.menu-icon').click();   
   })
})
```